# How to retrieve the kth element In subarray with given range in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I Have an array that values in it is :

```
int[] elements = {4 , 7 , 3 , 6 ,2 ,5 ,1};
```

**The users input is (k,i,j) That K means the Kth index in range (i,j)**

If The user's input is **(3,0,6)** The Answer Must be **3** Cause The **3rd** Index in range **(0,6)** is **3**.

How Can I retrieve the Kth index and print The index's value ?

Comment: `elements[k+i]`? (assuming it's in range)

Comment: @Eran `elements[i + k - 1]`

Comment: @YCF_L i want to determine the range then retreive it, How to get range ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your code.

Comment: did you mean `int result = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, i, j)[k - 1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] elements = { 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1 };
        printKth(elements, 3, 0, 6);
        printKth(elements, 3, 1, 5);
        printKth(elements, 2, 2, 6);
    }

    static void printKth(int[] element, int k, int i, int j) {
        if ((i + k - 1) < element.length)
            System.out.println(element[i + k - 1]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
6
6
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Fast Reply.That Is Correct.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be creating your own function which takes one *subarray* from the *original* one using `begin` and `end` indexes.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public static int[] subArray(int[] array, int beg, int end) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, beg, end + 1);
}
```

Then just use below *function* to access your `k - 1` element.

```
int[] subarray = subArray(arr, beg, end);
System.out.println(subarray[k - 1]);
```

Comment: Yes , Another Approach is this.Thanks